# Permutating over row

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I am new to SQL and trying to permutate a matrix in SQL in a single statement.

I have tried to use order by, but I am unsure of how to go about it, since this approach would require to order-by the rows, twice.

currently I am trying:

```
select * from matrix, order by i=1;
select * from matrix, order by i desc;
```

[rows- i
columns- j
values- val]

Original matrix:

```
1, 2, 3
4, 5, 6
7, 8, 2
```

Desired Matrix:

```
7, 8, 2
1, 2, 3
4, 5, 6
```

(row 0->1, 1->2, 2->0)

I would like to achieve the desired matrix in a single sql query.

Comment: This is not really how you would store a matrix in SQL.  In particular, SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so your table isn't really a matrix, despite its name.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the first column of the matric represents the order of your records (which your sample data tends to indicate), this can be achieved using window functions (available on most RDBMS, but usually not on all versions).

You can use `LEAD(c1) OVER(ORDER BY c1)` to retrieve the id of the next record, and use this value to sort the results :

```
SELECT * FROM mytable t ORDER BY LEAD(c1) OVER(ORDER BY c1);
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4ad5e457fa5df002688674db995269d5)** :

```
WITH mytable AS (SELECT 1 c1, 2 c2, 3 c3 UNION ALL SELECT 4, 5, 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7, 8, 2)
SELECT * FROM mytable t ORDER BY LEAD(c1) OVER(ORDER BY c1);
GO
```

```
 c1 | c2 | c3
 -: | -: | -:
  7 |  8 |  2
  1 |  2 |  3
  4 |  5 |  6
```